# Conversation with google assistant sdk

Tags: raspberry-pi3, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-aiy

I'm working with the google voice-aiy kit.

As far as I see with the assistant-sdk you should continuously say "Ok google" to ask one question and then start over if you want another one.

How this work with a DialogFlow app? Is it integrated?

When I try to talk to my app deployed to dialogflow it says to me "your  is not available on this device"

Comment: There was a bug relating to the Assistant SDK library. Can you update your version to the latest (0.4.1) and re-register your device with the hotword sample? It should work.

Comment: Unfortunately I keep getting "<appName> isn't supported on this device". I've just tried also with NumberGenie but the result is always the same

Comment: There's probably a bug in the library. I'll look into it in more depth next week.

Comment: any news on this?

Comment: It is a bug, but no update on the fix yet. https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/147